# Responsive joomla menu toggle button won't open

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm using bootstrap and joomla 3 to build a template (http://lucapadovani.com/tese-beta/) and having some issues with 2 responsive navbars: when I click on the toggle buttons the menus simply do not open. I guess there might be some kind of conflict between joomla "bootstrap.framework" and other js related stuff, but all of this is quite new for me, so I'm not sure how to solve the problem. Any help? Thx.

### Index.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

  // Add JavaScript Frameworks
  JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

  // Load optional Bootstrap bugfixes
  JHtmlBootstrap::loadCss($includeMaincss = true);

  // Check homepage
  $defaultMenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getDefault()->id;
  $currentMenu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

  if($defaultMenu == $currentMenu){ 
     $bodyId = 'id="home"'; 
     $homePage = true; 
  }else{
     $bodyId = ''; 
     $homePage = false; 
  }

  // Logo file or site title param
  if ($this->params->get('logoFile'))
  {
    $logo = '<img src="'. JURI::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile') .'" alt=" Tese"  />';
  }

?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Include optional regions in the template -->
<?php
 $this->_scripts = array();
?>

<jdoc:include type="head" />

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!-- Stylesheets listed below 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />-->   
<!-- Bootstrap styling -->
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<?php
  // Header color
  if ($this->params->get('headerColor'))
  {
  ?>

  <style type="text/css">
    header{
      background:<?php echo $this->params->get('headerColor');?>;  
    }
  </style>

  <?php
  }
?>

<?php
  // Top menu (active-item) color
  if ($this->params->get('topColor'))
  {
  ?>

  <style type="text/css">
    .topheader .navbar-inverse .nav .active>a,
    .topheader .navbar-inverse .nav .active>a:hover,
    .topheader .navbar-inverse .nav .active>a:focus {
      background-color:<?php echo $this->params->get('topColor');?>;
    }
  </style>

  <?php
  }
?>

<?php
  // Menu color
  if ($this->params->get('menuColor'))
  {
  ?>

  <style type="text/css">
    #mainnav.navbar-inverse .nav .active>a,
    #mainnav.navbar-inverse .nav .active>a,
    #mainnav.navbar-inverse .nav .active>a {
      background-color:<?php echo $this->params->get('menuColor');?>;
    }
  </style>

  <?php
  }
?> 


<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container all"><!--Page container-->

<!--===Top===-->
<div class="row topheader">
    <div class="col-sm-12">  
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="topnav">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Tese</a>
            </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="topmenu" style="html5" />
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><jdoc:include type="modules" name="socialnetworks" style="html5" /></li>
                    <li><jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="html5" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<!--===/top===-->

<!--===Header===-->
<header class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 logo"><?php echo $logo;?></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="mainnav">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex2-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Menu</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex2-collapse">
              <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="html5" />
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>  
    </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="join" style="html5" />
    </div>
</header>
<!--===/header===-->


<!--===Home-only layout===-->
<?php if($homePage == true): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="html5" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="areas">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="buttons" style="html5" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="intro">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="about" style="html5" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="news">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="content1" style="html5" /></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="component" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="partners">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="partners" style="html5" /></div>
    </div>
<? endif; ?> 
<!--===/home-only layout===-->

<!--===Page layout===-->
<?php if($homePage == false): ?>

    <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="breadcrumb" style="html5" />
    </div>
  <!-- W/ module right: 2 columns layout -->
  <?php if ($this->countModules('right')): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9" id="main">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content1" style="html5" />
          <jdoc:include type="component" />
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content2" style="html5" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="sidebar">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="html5" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Else: 1 column layout -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content1" style="html5" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="content2" style="html5" />
    </div>
    <? endif; ?>

<? endif; ?>
<!--===/page layout===-->

<!--===Footer===-->
<footer class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer1" style="html5" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer2" style="html5" /></div>
</footer>
<!--===/footer===-->


</div><!--/page container-->

<!--<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the link provided by you.

There are couple of Javascript errors. That you have needed to fix.

JS Error: window.addEvent - addEvent method is undefined. Here, window.addEvent is mootool Javascript library method. I checked it, in your page, I couldn't able to find the reference of mootool library.

JS Error - autocompleter.js - "Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined". This should be resolved after you will add mootools JS link.

You could find that in "media\system\js\mootools-core.js".

As, working with Jquery and mootools requires jquery-noconflict.js. You also need to take care of "jquery-noconflict.js", which you could find it in "media\jui\js\jquery-noconflict.js".

So, make sure to remove the Javascript errors to make your functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Mayurkumar Vandra, but I'm still a bit confused.
I added Mootools and Jquery in no-conflict mode, as you suggested, however I wasn't able either to fix the errors you mentioned - which I believe are related to some third party plugins I installed - or to make the toggle button work. One weird thing, yet: if I comment the line JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');, the button toggles once and almost unstyled, but then doesn't work again.

Help! Thx